# $.get loads incorrect url when attempting to load angular component inside of an iframe

Tags: jquery, angular, ajax, iframe

I am trying to load an angular component inside of an iframe and display that inside of a a dialog displayed when a user clicks a link on an aspx page. Previously the dialog displayed another aspx page contents but we are replacing it with an angular component. The angular project has a main app router which uses lazy loading to load the modules for the other components when the corresponding route is accessed. I am able to access the correct url by just going to a new window and typing 'http://localhost:82/app/s/invoice' but when I attempt to load the url with ajax and write it to the iframe I am redirected to angular projects home page. This happens whenever there is no matching route found by the angular router.

After many slight variations on this I enabled tracing in the router like this:

```
[RouterModule.forRoot(routes
     , { enableTracing: true }//logging
```

and checked the results in the console to see which route was actually being hit.

For some reason the actual url that is being passed into the angular router for matching is the same as the relative url of the current aspx page that the user is clicking the link from instead of the url that I am passing into the jquery ajax get function. Here is an example of the the way that I am trying to do my ajax call:

```
$.get('/app/s/invoice', function (ret) {
    // this is the iframe within the div we're going to load
    var frm = $('#uploadsrc')[0].contentWindow.document;

    frm.open();
    frm.write(ret); // Write the upload form to the iframe
    frm.close();
});
```

and an example of the route that is actually being passed into the angular router:

```
/sales/so.aspx?key=123
```

Hoping that someone might know of anything that can cause the jquery get function to default to a url other than the one provided in the actual function call or how to possibly prevent that kind of thing from happening.

Edit for some additional information:

I can get the iframe to open the angular component by removing the ajax call and instead just specifying the src attribute on the iframe element to be the url that I want to display. This is fine for a fallback but it is preferable to only load the angular component if the user actually clicks the link.

Thanks in advance.